# Change number_format datatype

Tags: phpexcel, number-formatting

How do I convert to double the returned value of the php function, `number_format();`

Here's my code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colmun_alpha[$col_count+1].$row,number_format($items[0][1],2));
```

I need `number_format($items[0][1],2)` for the purpose of displaying it nicely in Excel. But
I the sum function of excel doesn't work because `$items[0][1]` is formatted to string.

I need somehow to format it just like the number_format do but with a datatype of double / float.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please indicate code in your question using the markup instructions. It makes it much easier to read

Comment: Don't use PHP's number_format to format values written to cells; simply set the cell value as a normal PHP float, and apply an __Excel__ number format mask style to the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items[0][1] = 12345.678;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue($colmun_alpha[$col_count+1].$row, $items[0][1]);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($colmun_alpha[$col_count+1].$row)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use typecasting to ensure that the variable has a float type.

```
number_format( (float) $items[0][1],2)
```

if this doesnt work then maybe something else is not working properly in your code